# Android Broadcast Receiver called but not running

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, alarmmanager

I have created a broad cast receiver and alarm manager (the following code):

AlarmManager

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 18);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        // Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                1234567890, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

MyReciever

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("SERVICE RECIEVED");
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
        context.startService(service1);
    }

}
```

MyAlarmService

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service {

    private NotificationManager mManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(
                        this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Alarm", System.currentTimeMillis());
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(),
                "Alarm", "Open the app now",
                pendingNotificationIntent);

        mManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
 <service
            android:name=".MyAlarmService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"/>
```

The issue I am having is that the Alarm Manager is running and calling the MyReceiver class but nothing is happening as it should. I know that its calling the function because in the log cat the following is displaying:

```
11-18 11:18:00.415: I/ActivityManager(765): START u0 {flg=0x4 cmp=pacakge/.MyReceiver (has extras)} from pid -1
```

The package value is the package name.

Can someone please explain where its going wrong? The alarm call works but the functions don't run.

Comment: what is not working??

Comment: intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
            1234567890, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

instead of

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            1234567890, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Changing getActivity to getBroadcast worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

`onStart` was deprecated in API 5.

Change it to `onStartCommand`. Follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int))

Hope it helps